# How to run a Java console application all the time?

Tags: java, linux, gradle, ubuntu-14.04, daemon

I have a server (Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS) and want a certain Java application to run on it all the time. Currently I start it using `nohup gradle run &`. Yesterday it stopped working. `nohup.out` shows the following error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 137
```

How do I need to change my Java application to prevent such errors in future (make sure that the application runs all the time and -- ideally -- is restarted automatically, if it crashes) ? I'm looking for simple, minimal solutions.

Note that I had similar issues on servers of this particular company before. I had an Apache server with a web application and sometimes it would stop working for no apparent reason (maybe the server was put to sleep because of low activity, no idea).

**Update 1 (27.01.2017 12:30 MSK):** I modified the Gradle code to log memory dump in case of OutOfMemoryError.

```
run {
    jvmArgs = ["-Xmx100m", "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError", "-XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/dp/dev/myprod/log/memdump.log"]
}
```

When I run the Gradle script I see following message in the output, from which I conclude that memory dump arguments are defined correctly.

```
09:33:47.031 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Starting process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java''. Working directory: /home/dp/dev/myprod Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/dp/dev/myprod/log/memdump.log [...] com.mycompany.myprod.AppKt
```

After the application crashed, I don't see a file `/home/dp/dev/myprod/log/memdump.log`. Directory `/home/dp/dev/myprod/log/` exists and is accessible by the user, who starts the application.

I launch the application using `nohup gradle --full-stacktrace --stacktrace --debug run &`, but it doesn't help get any meaningful information about the cause of the problem.

Here's the exception I get:

```
06:29:16.179 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 137
06:29:16.180 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
06:29:16.186 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:31)
06:29:16.186 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:74)
06:29:16.186 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
06:29:16.186 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:136)
06:29:16.187 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:129)
06:29:16.187 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:118)
06:29:16.187 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:623)
06:29:16.187 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:606)
06:29:16.187 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
06:29:16.188 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
06:29:16.194 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 68 more
06:29:16.205 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Comment: 137 is out of memory. you might have memory leak

Comment: you also might work on your title

Comment: do you run it as a simple "java application" or you run in on a server like tomcat? are you using jenkins?

Comment: @RudiDudi Simple Java (Kotlin, actually) application. I use neither Tomcat, nor Jenkins.

Comment: @PhilippSander See my update 1. How do I diagnose an OutOfMemoryError in absence of a memory dump?

Comment: Beside the OOM that should be fixed. You should install your application as a service. following link might give you ideas: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Basically, it's not a good practice. You should avoid such usage of build tool, and pack it to an executable JAR before running. If you need to resolve artifacts during startup for some reason take a look on [Capsule project](http://www.capsule.io/) and [Gradle Capsule Plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/us.kirchmeier.capsule).
2. Gradle 3.+ is using Daemon by default. If it has been idle for 3 hours or more Gradle will kill the Daemon. I'm not sure that this is the reason, but you can try to start with `--no-daemon` argument.

Comment: I've created a fat JAR and launched it more than 24 hours ago. Until now there was no problem with the application. So you are probably right.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments it is an Out Of Memory Exception, you can do:

Rewiev you code, maybe you can have low performances in your code.

If you are running a simple "java application" you can, instead click "Run As.. Java Application" click "Run As.. Run Configration", select your java application and in TAB "Arguments", "VM Arguments" add this parameters:

```
-Xmx1024m -Xms512m
```

with this parameters you allocate a minimum of 512M on your application (at the start) and a maximum of 1024M. You can enlarge this numbers as needed.

Comment: this does not fix a memory leak!

Answer (score 0):

First, You should try to find and resolve the Out Of Memory issue in your application.

To setup monitoring you can write a simple script that checks if your applications is running .
Either check if the application is listening to the designated port or check using

```
ps aux
```

or any other way that suits you.

If application is down , restart it.

Now set a cron that runs this script every few minutes.
something like

```
*/10 * * * * /your/script
```

This will run your script every 10 minutes.